# Blogger: Facebook Sharer Catches Site Logo Instead Of Post Image

Tags: facebook, blogger, facebook-opengraph

I have a website hosted on blogger http://www.dragonballtown.net, When I try to share the website post in facebook, it shows my website logo instead of post image.

I'm using these Open graph Meta tags:-

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageTitle' property='og:title'/>
<meta content='blog' property='og:type'/>
<b:else/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>
<meta content='article' property='og:type'/>
</b:if>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.canonicalUrl' property='og:url'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:site_name'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
<b:else/>
<meta content='blog-logo.jpg' property='og:image'/>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription != &quot;&quot;'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' name='og:description'/>
</b:if>
```

But this is not working for me, I tried facebook open graph debugger to re-scrape site but it's still showing logo image with post url while sharing on facebook

Comment: Just check the source code of that page in your browser - there is no `og:image` meta tag.

Comment: I ran a post through the debugger (Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dragonballtown.net%2F2017%2F08%2Fdragon-ball-super-episode-103-subbed.html ) and it seems to be showing correctly now. Also, If your blog already has the `<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>` tag present in the `head` section of the theme, there is no need to explicitly include another `og:image` tag as that is already included by the `all-head-content` tag on every page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' property='og:image' />
<b:else/>
     <meta content='blog-logo.jpg' property='og:image' />
</b:if>
```

Change `data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl` with `data:blog.postImageUrl` make sure it rendered, view source code of your site on item pages.